# Execution Monitoring of SSIS packages

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

How can we monitor the progress of an **SSIS** package during its execution ? I would want to know which executable is presently running, how many rows read/processed/written, executable execution duration, events raised etc while a package is executing.

In Ab Inito we can monitor these parameters by looking at a log file which gets generated during package execution with similar information that gets appended to the log file as the execution progresses.

Is there any similar way to do the same with SSIS packages ?

**I am using Sql-Server 2012

Comment: Are you using the Project deployment model or the Package deployment model with your 2012 installation?

Comment: I am using Project Deployment Model... However I have the freedom to choose either of them if at all required.

Answer (score 0):

For information on executables and events, take a look at the views available in your SSISDB database, specifically at catalog.executions and catalog.event_messages.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 *
  FROM [SSISDB].[catalog].[executions]
```

While some row-count like aggregations are included in event messages, more detailed information may need to be intentionally logged from within the SSIS packages.